ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API : can not update database when using EF Core lazy loading with proxies
I'm using EF Core 6.0 with lazy loading.
I have added the package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies and I have added UseLazyLoadingProxies() in my DbContext:
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies().UseSqlServer("Server = SRV84; Database = BASE_DEMO1; User Id = sa; Password = Ab@123456");
    }
}

This is my API:
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateUser(UserCreateDto oUserCreate) //UserCreateDto oUserCreate
{
    var oUser = await _authorizationService.GetUserByUserName(oUserCreate.Username);

    if (oUser.Id > 0)
    {
        return BadRequest("Username already exists");
    }

    oUserCreate.Status = (int)StatusUser.Deactive;
    oUserCreate.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    oUserCreate.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
    oUserCreate.Status = (int)StatusUser.Deactive;

    var idUser = await _authorizationService.CreateUser(oUserCreate);

    if (idUser == 0)
    {
        await AddLogAsync(UserIdentity.FullName + ": create " + oUserCreate.FullName, OBJECT.USERS, (int)ActionLogs.Add, (int)StatusLogs.Error);
        return BadRequest("There was an error!");
    }

    await AddLogAsync(UserIdentity.FullName + ": create " + oUserCreate.FullName, OBJECT.USERS, (int)ActionLogs.Add, (int)StatusLogs.Success);

    #region Create new Userinfo   
    UserInfoCreateDto userInfo = new UserInfoCreateDto();
    userInfo.Address = oUserCreate.Address;
    userInfo.Email = oUserCreate.Email;
    userInfo.Avatar = oUserCreate.Avatar;
    userInfo.Phone = oUserCreate.PhoneNumber;
    userInfo.Sex = oUserCreate.Sex;
    userInfo.UserId = idUser;

    await BaseService.CreateAsync<UserDetail, UserInfoCreateDto>(userInfo);
    #endregion

    #region Create new Group   
    if (oUserCreate.GroupIds.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var item in oUserCreate.GroupIds)
        {
            if (item > 0)
            {
                await BaseService.CreateAsync<GroupUser, GroupUserCreateDto>(new GroupUserCreateDto() { GroupId = item, UserId = idUser });
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    return Ok();
}

[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsers([FromQuery] UserGridPagingDto pagingModel)
{
    var predicates = pagingModel.GetPredicates();
    var result = await BaseService.FilterPagedAsync<User, UserGridDto>(pagingModel, predicates.ToArray());

    if (pagingModel.GroupId > 0)
    {
        if (result.Data.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < result.Data.Count; i++)
            {
                result.Data[i].IsCheck = result.Data[i].LstGroupIds.Contains(pagingModel.GroupId);
            }
        }
    }

    return Ok(result);
}

When I post 'User' from API, my database cannot update, but I could get data.
I try to delete my database, comment my connection string & restart my computer. But I still could get data that I added before.
This is what I see in the terminal:
16' with options: using lazy loading proxies
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (52ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM [Users] AS [u]
      WHERE [u].[DeletedUserId] IS NULL
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (52ms) [Parameters=[@__p_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [t].[Id], [t].[UserName], [t].[FullName], [t].[c], [t].[Status], [t].[CreatedDate], [t].[DeletedUserId], [t].[c0], [g].[GroupId], [g].[Id]
      FROM (
          SELECT TOP(@__p_0) [u].[Id], [u].[UserName], [u].[FullName], (
              SELECT TOP(1) [u0].[Email]
              FROM [UserDetail] AS [u0]
              WHERE [u].[Id] = [u0].[UserId]) AS [c], [u].[Status], [u].[CreatedDate], [u].[DeletedUserId], (
              SELECT TOP(1) [u1].[Phone]
              FROM [UserDetail] AS [u1]
              WHERE [u].[Id] = [u1].[UserId]) AS [c0]
          FROM [Users] AS [u]
          WHERE [u].[DeletedUserId] IS NULL
          ORDER BY [u].[Id] DESC
      ) AS [t]
      LEFT JOIN [GroupUser] AS [g] ON [t].[Id] = [g].[UserId]
      ORDER BY [t].[Id] DESC

What should I do now?

You need to await SaveChangesAsync() on the DbContext to actually commit any changes to data mapped to EFcore objects

I don't see any INSERT statements in your logs. Seems like you are not actually saving anything back to your db, but we can't see how you are using your dbContext
